# How to get age from the date expressed by integer

Tags: c, date, integer

I need to convert the date into the age, but I have the specific format of the date:[image: here's the example of my data]

I have to convert it in relation to a specific date (1.1.2021). Could you help me?

Comment: look at *mktime* for instance, get a date and time in 'human' definition and compute the time in seconds, you can do diff of times in seconds. For reverse conversion *gmtime* for instance

Answer (score 0):

Get the current time in a `struct tm` using [time(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) and [localtime(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html):

```
#include <time.h>
struct tm * current_time = localtime(time(NULL));
```

Read the dates and then convert them to a `struct tm` as well using [strptime(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3p.html):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>

char * date = "19.06.2018 07:49:16";
struct tm birth_time;
strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", &birth_time);
```

After you have the current time and birth time structures, you can simply calculate the age using the `tm_year`, `tm_mon` and `tm_mday` members of the structures.

I wrote a program that performs the task you needed, hope it would make things clearer:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DATE_DELIMITER (' ')
#define DATE_FORMAT ("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
#define MAX_LINE_LEN (1000)

size_t get_num_of_dates_in_line(char * line)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    assert(NULL != line);

    for (i = 0; '\0' != line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (DATE_DELIMITER == line[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    /* divide by 2 since there are 2 delimiters between each different date,
       add +1 for date after last delimiter. */
    return (count / 2) + 1;
}

void free_dates(char *** dates, size_t n)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    assert(NULL != dates);

    if (NULL != *dates)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (NULL != (*dates)[i])
            {
                free((*dates)[i]);
            }
        }

        free(*dates);
        *dates = NULL;
    }
}

char * get_next_date_from_line(char * line, size_t * offset)
{
    int failure = -1;
    char * date = NULL;
    size_t date_len = 0;
    size_t temp_offset = 0;
    char * delim_ptr = NULL;

    assert(NULL != line);
    assert(NULL != offset);

    delim_ptr = strchr(line, DATE_DELIMITER);
    if (NULL == delim_ptr)
    {
        /* Line completely consumed - success */
        failure = 0;
        goto l_cleanup;
    }
    temp_offset = delim_ptr - line + 1; /* +1 to skip delimiter */
    
    /* Skip second delimiter since there are 2 between each date */
    delim_ptr = strchr(line + temp_offset, DATE_DELIMITER);
    if (NULL == delim_ptr)
    {
        /* Reached the end of the line */
        delim_ptr = strchr(line + temp_offset, '\0');
        if (NULL == delim_ptr)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "line format error.\n");
            goto l_cleanup;
        }

        if ('\n' == line[delim_ptr - line - 1])
        {
            delim_ptr--;
        }
    }
    date_len = delim_ptr - line + 1;

    date = (char *)calloc(date_len, 1);
    if (NULL == date)
    {
        perror("calloc failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    strncpy(date, line, date_len - 1); /* -1 so we dont copy delimiter */
    
    *offset += date_len;
    failure = 0;

l_cleanup:
    if (failure)
    {
        if (NULL != date)
        {
            free(date);
            date = NULL;
        }
    }
    return date;
}

char ** get_birth_dates(size_t * num_of_dates, FILE * fp)
{
    int failure = -1;
    char ** birth_dates = NULL;
    char ** realloc_retval = NULL;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN] = {0};
    size_t total = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t offset = 0;
    char * date = NULL;

    assert(NULL != num_of_dates);
    assert(NULL != fp);

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp))
    {
        count = get_num_of_dates_in_line(line);

        realloc_retval = (char **)realloc(
            birth_dates, sizeof(*birth_dates) * (total + count)
        );
        if (NULL == realloc_retval)
        {
            perror("realloc failed");
            goto l_cleanup;
        }
        birth_dates = realloc_retval;
        total += count;

        offset = 0;
        while ((date = get_next_date_from_line(line + offset, &offset)))
        {
            birth_dates[i++] = date;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fp))
    {
        perror("fgets failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    *num_of_dates = total;
    failure = 0;

l_cleanup:
    if (failure)
    {
        free_dates(&birth_dates, total);
    }
    return birth_dates;
}

int get_current_time(struct tm * curr_time)
{
    int ret_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    time_t t = (time_t)-1;

    assert(NULL != curr_time);

    t = time(NULL);
    if ((time_t)-1 == t)
    {
        perror("time failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    if (NULL == localtime_r(&t, curr_time))
    {
        perror("localtime failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    ret_code = EXIT_SUCCESS;

l_cleanup:
    return ret_code;
}

unsigned int calculate_age(struct tm curr_time, struct tm birth_time)
{
    unsigned int age = 0;

    age = curr_time.tm_year - birth_time.tm_year;

    /* Adjust the age if we're not yet past that date in
       the current year. */
    if ((curr_time.tm_mon > birth_time.tm_mon) ||
            ((curr_time.tm_mon == birth_time.tm_mon) &&
             (curr_time.tm_mday > birth_time.tm_mday)))
    {
        age--;
    }

    return age;
}

unsigned int * parse_birth_dates_to_ages(char ** birth_dates,
                                         size_t num_of_dates)
{
    int failure = -1;
    unsigned int * ages = NULL;
    struct tm birth_time;
    struct tm curr_time;
    size_t i = 0;

    memset(&birth_time, 0, sizeof(birth_time));
    memset(&curr_time, 0, sizeof(curr_time));

    assert(NULL != birth_dates);
    assert(0 != num_of_dates);

    ages = (unsigned int *)calloc(num_of_dates, sizeof(*ages));
    if (NULL == ages)
    {
        perror("calloc failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    if (get_current_time(&curr_time))
        goto l_cleanup;

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_dates; i++)
    {
        if (NULL == strptime(birth_dates[i], DATE_FORMAT, &birth_time))
        {
            perror("strptime failed");
            goto l_cleanup;
        }

        ages[i] = calculate_age(curr_time, birth_time);
    }

    failure = 0;

l_cleanup:
    if (failure)
    {
        if (NULL != ages)
        {
            free(ages);
            ages = NULL;
        }
    }
    return ages;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    char ** birth_dates = NULL;
    unsigned int * ages = NULL;
    size_t amount = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    
    fp = fopen("birth_dates.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        perror("fopen failed");
        goto l_cleanup;
    }

    birth_dates = get_birth_dates(&amount, fp);
    if (NULL == birth_dates)
        goto l_cleanup;

    ages = parse_birth_dates_to_ages(birth_dates, amount);
    if (NULL == ages)
        goto l_cleanup;

    printf("Ages:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        printf("[%zu] %u\n", i + 1, ages[i]);
    }

    ret_code = EXIT_SUCCESS;

l_cleanup:
    free_dates(&birth_dates, amount);
    if (NULL != ages)
    {
        free(ages);
    }
    if (NULL != fp)
    {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return ret_code;
}
```

The input file `birth_dates.txt` is the following:

> 19.06.2018 07:49:16 20.06.2018 07:50:24 20.06.2012 10:00:20
> 12.07.2002 01:01:16 05.01.1987 12:08:10 25.02.2000 14:50:02